# How can I change value of textbox in controller in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form for sending email in asp.net mvc4
when user clicks on submit button,after the email sent successfully all of text box in my form become empty

my view code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
 <table cellpadding="5px;">
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.Label("Name")</td>
         <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Name)</td>
         <td class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Name)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.Label("From")</td>
         <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.From)</td>
         <td class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.From)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.Label("Email")</td>
         <td>@Html.DropDownList("Email",new SelectList(Emaillist,"Value","Text"))</td>
         <td class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Email)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.Label("Subject")</td>
         <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject)</td>
         <td class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Subject)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.Label("Text")</td>
         <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body)</td>
         <td class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Body)</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 <br/>
 <br/>

<span style="color: red; font-size: 14px;">@ViewBag.Message</span>   
 }
```

my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(Contact contact)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("MyEmail Address");
                MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(contact.Email);
                const string fromPassword = "My Password Address";
                string subject = contact.Subject;
                string body = "From: " + ViewBag.Name + "\nEmail: " + contact.From + "\n\n\n Body: " + contact.Body;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "Host";
                smtp.Port = port;
                smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword);

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = body;

                smtp.Send(message);
                ViewBag.Message = "Your message send successfully ";
                return View("Contact");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                ViewBag.Message = "Your message doesn't send, please try again" + "\n" + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

How can I change value of textbox in controller after send email?

what code should I add after "smtp.Send(message)" in order to my textbox in view become empty?

Comment: did you tried anything in  the client side..like jQuery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display values after sending mail

```
return View("Contact", contact);
```

If you want to clear values then Either set values empty manually like contact.Subject = "";...etc and return as above OR you can create new contact object and pass it with view

```
return View("Contact", new Contact());
```

Comment: thanks but your code make empty my Contact class.The values that user entered stay in page yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your view model back to the view at the end of the ActionResult.

```
return View("Contact", contact);
```